# Не находит функцию в .dll (c#)

Tags: c#, winapi, dll, c#-7.0

Не находит функцию в .dll, которую подключаю(funcPtr == 0). Предполагаю, что имя функции либо кодируется, либо меняется как-то внутри, но сам пока не могу понять.

Программа:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Lab1Dynamic
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string lpFileName);

        [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "GetProcAddress")]
        static extern IntPtr GetProcAddressOrdinal(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr procName);

        private delegate double fDelegate(double x, double y);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dllPath = "MyLibrary.dll";
            IntPtr dllInstance = LoadLibrary(dllPath);
            while (dllInstance == IntPtr.Zero)
            {    
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Can't load DLL " + dllPath);

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.WriteLine("Write the path below...");
                dllPath = Console.ReadLine();
                dllInstance = LoadLibrary(dllPath);
            }

            string fname = "f";
            IntPtr funcPtr = GetProcAddress(dllInstance, fname);
            fDelegate fd = (fDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(funcPtr,
                typeof(fDelegate));
            var y = fd(1.0, 2.0);
        }
    }
}
```

DLL:

```
using System;

namespace MyProj
{
    public class MyLibrary
    {
        public static double f(double x, double y) => 3 * Math.Sin(x) + 2 * Math.Cos(y);
    }
}
```

DLL(C++, VS2019):
MyLib.h:

```
#pragma once
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double f(const double x, const double y);
```

MyLib.cpp:

```
#include "MyLib.h"
#include "pch.h"
#include <cmath>
double f(const double x, const double y)
{
    return 3 * sin(x) + 2 * cos(y);
}
```

P.S. Делал по гайду от MDSN [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Для чего вам в данном случае `WinAPI`, если `dll` у вас представляет управляемый код (сборку)?! Вам нужно использовать методы определенные в `System.Reflection` для загрузки в текущий домен приложений (`AppDomain`) сборки и последующим вызовом метода.

Comment: @gregzakharov таково задание лабораторной, нужно загрузить именно с помощью LoadLibrary, GetProcAddress, FreeLibrary.

Comment: Тогда и пишите неуправляемый код `dll`, чтобы можно было через `WinAPI` все сделать.

Comment: @gregzakharov может скажете, как сделать, чтобы GetProcAddress находила функцию в .dll?

Comment: Уже ответил. А если до вас не доходит, увы.

Comment: @gregzakharov писать тут секции unsafe с использованием этих всех указателей на указатели и тд - это только наваливать кучу хлама.

Comment: При чем здесь небезопасный код, уважаемый? Вам было сказано "неуправляемый", что на пальцах означает буквально следующее: берете C\C++\Asm, реализуете код библиотеки, компилируете, далее на C# реализуете класс SafeLoadLibrary с нужными `WinAPI` функциями, компилируете - профит.

Comment: Вам нужно сделать DLL на языке C, а не C#. В интернете полно мануалов на эту тему. Например, вот: https://www.codementor.io/@a_hathon/building-and-using-dlls-in-c-d7rrd4caz. Причина неудачи вашего решения в том, что за словом DLL в Windows скрываются два совершенно разных класса объектов. То, что вы сделали - это assembly технологии .NET, считайте, байткод промежуточного языка. Вы же хотите работать с машинным кодом (на это намекает GetDelegateForFunctionPointer). Значит вам и DLL нужна в машинных кодах, то есть скомпилированная из языков Си или Си++.

Comment: @PakUula "То, что вы сделали - это assembly технологии .NET, считайте, байткод промежуточного языка. Вы же хотите работать с машинным кодом (на это намекает GetDelegateForFunctionPointer)". Я попытался использовать делегат, потому что не знаю другого способа. А если я не хочу работать с машинным, то что использовать и можно ли все провернуть на шарпе, не идя в си и си++?

Comment: @PakUula написал и собрал библиотеку на С++, такое же имя функции сделал, в С# подключаю и опять не находит имя.

Comment: @HideME, Ваше приложение написано на С#, и таковым и останется. Функция `GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` оборачивает Сишную функцию, после чего её можно вызывать из C#. Оставьте приложение как есть, просто переделайте DLL. Функции LoadLibrary, GetProcAddress, FreeLibrary работают именно с Сишными библиотеками, и только с ними. Поэтому вам и библиотека нужна написанная на Си.

Comment: @HideME, Обновите текст вопроса, добавьте туда код библиотеки. Я подозреваю, вы не поставили либо EXPORT, либо extern "C"

Comment: @PakUula спасибо за ваше терпение, обновил.

Comment: Убедитесь, что вы грузите именно ту DLL, которую скомпилировали в VC. Что возвращает команда `dumpbin /exports <nameofdll>`? (эта команда должна быть где-то в недрах VS, печатает содержимое таблицы экспорта)

Comment: @PakUula [ссылка](https://imgur.com/a/RduZkWw)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104435/discussion-between-pak-uula-and-hideme).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое на что стоит обратить внимание, это на то, какое соглашение используется в вашем проекте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее, при формировании делегата на неуправляемую импортируемую функцию, вам необходимо добавить соответствующий атрибут:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate double ImportFDelegate(double x, double y);
```

Далее при запросе указателя на неуправляемую функцию, убедитесь что вы передаете правильное имя функции:

В моем случае:

```
C:\Users\ヒミコ\source\repos\SO\Debug>dumpbin /exports MyLib.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.24.28316.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file MyLib.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for MyLib.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           1 number of functions
           1 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 0001117C f = @ILT+375(_f) // Здесь указано экспортированное имя, и реальное, реальное с подчеркиванием
                                           // подробнее на MSDN https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions?view=vs-2019

  Summary

        1000 .00cfg
        1000 .data
        1000 .idata
        1000 .msvcjmc
        2000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        6000 .text
       10000 .textbss

C:\Users\ヒミコ\source\repos\SO\Debug>
```

Так же убедитесь в том что разрядность проектов соответствует, т.е. если библиотека x86, то и проект на c# x86, с x64 то же самое.

Далее просто привожу код исправленный:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr moduleHandle);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate double ImportFDelegate(double x, double y);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dllPath = "MyLibrary.dll";
        IntPtr dllInstance = LoadLibrary(dllPath);

        while (dllInstance == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Win32Exception exception = new Win32Exception(errorCode);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to load library {1}:\n\t{0}", exception.Message, Path.GetFileName(dllPath));

            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.WriteLine("Write the path below...");
            dllPath = Console.ReadLine();
            dllInstance = LoadLibrary(dllPath);
        }

        const string functionName = "f";
        IntPtr funcPtr = GetProcAddress(dllInstance, functionName);

        if (funcPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Win32Exception exception = new Win32Exception(errorCode);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to get address of function: {0}\n\t{1}", functionName, exception.Message);
            return;
        }

        ImportFDelegate fd = (ImportFDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(funcPtr, typeof(ImportFDelegate));
        double result = fd(1.0, 2.0);

        Console.WriteLine("Imported function return result: {0:N}", result);

        FreeLibrary(dllInstance);
    }
}
```

Ну и собственно вывод программы:

```
Unable to load library MyLibrary.dll:
        Не найден указанный модуль
Write the path below...
MyLib.dll
Imported function return result: 1,69
```